# JQuery: 1 datepicker From date to constrain the To date

Tags: jquery

The user has to enter a Date From field and a Date To field.
The Date To field must be after Date From.
How do I enforce this in JQuery?
My current code does not work, not even by giving a default date.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $('#DateFrom').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear:true, yearRange: 'c-1:c+1' });
    $('#DateTo').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: 'c-1:c+1' });
    $('#DateFrom').datepicker({ onSelect: function (dateStr) {
        $('#DateTo').datepicker({ defaultDate: dateStr });
    }
    });
    $('#DateTo').datepicker();

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the minValue option of the datepicker.
Sample below:

```
<input type="text" id="from">
<input type="text" id="to">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#to").datepicker();
    $("#from").datepicker().bind("change",function(){
        var minValue = $(this).val();
        minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", minValue);
        minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
        $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );
    })
});
</script>
```

Working exmaple @ http://jsfiddle.net/dW4n8/2/

Edit: Updated the sample to exclude the from date too.

Comment: Since your edit it has stopped working. In Firebug I get the error message 'uncaught exception: Unexpected literal at position 2'

Comment: What is the date format you are using for datepicker on your page?

Comment: I have noticed when using this method, the to date section is changed when selecting a from date. For example I set the default to value to TBC, which is OK on my form. But using your method when selecting the from date, the to field is wipped - is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Ah yes. In my original question you can see it is dd-MM-yy. So I changed it to that format and now it works. Thanks, I am very impressed with that.

Comment: @Scoobler: The to date value gets adjusted to the so that it is atleast the value of minDate that is set in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you have to add custom validation to the appropriate callbacks.
AFAIK there is no such thing as a minimum date in jquery datepickers.
I suggest you also take a look at onClose callback.